# Hide and show a popup when hover on with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Inside the 'nav', I want to show a popup when hovering on the last 'a' with jquery, but it doesn't work and I don't know where it goes wrong.
I tried to add visibility: hidden or display: none to .popup, nothing has happened. Wondering if I could get some help here.
Many thanks in advance.

I tried the same jquery code on another divs, it worked fine. I'm suspecting that something is wrong with HTML.

I fixed the problem by moving 'script scr' to the header.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = 294;
  canvas.height = 176;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contact").hover(function () {
      $('#popup').show();
    }, 
    function () {
      $('#popup').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home<a></li>
    <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="popup" id="popup">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take a look at how to ask -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please consider what you're asking. We can't see your screen, and we can't see your code. Consider creating a [mcve].

Comment: And please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 to understand why you should not post image of text.

Comment: I uploaded an image, but it hasn't shown up.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$( "div#contact" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $( '#popup' ).show();
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    // hide here
    // $('#service_menu').hide()
  });
```